# LM2596 bypasses resistor

Tags: soldering

I got a WINOMO LM2596 DC-DC 1.23-30V converter which I want to use to regulate the speed of an old PC fan.

[image]

I did not find a schematic for my specific converter, but I think this one should be close to it.

[image]
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9vMNa-H_PRg

I exchanged the potentiometer (top, blue)

[image]
http://www.ebay.de/itm/112589926880?clk_rvr_id=1415775361179&rmvSB=true

with this one

[image]
https://bilder5.eazyauction.de/ebaye70/auktionsbilder/2568_0NS_4881_1000x1000_0dc7819a.jpg

[image]

shows the cables that now go to the new potentiometer.

My setup works as intended only if I hold the converter in a specific position. When I wiggle/move the converter a little bit the fan speeds up with max. voltage, although the potentiometer is set in a position where it should not power on the fan. 
If I hold / fix the setup in the "right" position, I can regulate the fan speed as intended (and even turn off the fan when the voltage drops too much).

This leads me to believe that somehow the potentiometer gets bypassed due to poor connections somewhere or another effect I haven't figured out.

I added some pictures below, no cables are visible touching as far as I'm concerned.

I know that I did an extremely poor soldering job, desoldering the old potentiometer was a real piece of work due to my poor desoldering skills and then I just wanted to quickly connect everything to see if it works.

[image]
[image]
[image]

**edit**
I completely redid the question as I'm under the impression that it was hard to get what I actually did / what the problem is.

**edit2**
I disconnected the poti completely and the fan also spins with max voltage.

Comment: Include a **schematic** I'm not going to guess from the photo's what you did.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Added! Do you need any more information?

Comment: He means a schematic of the board itself that shows how your pot is wired in.

Comment: @DaveTweed I was not able to find a schematic of my board unfortunately. I added something I think should be close to the layout of the board judging from the pictures.

Comment: @idkfa - "*If placed right I can completely regulate the fan speed with the potentiometer [...] Even when I disconnect the 2 outer cables from the potentiometer (I kept the middle one connected during this) it shows the same behaviour.*" What *exactly* do you mean by "*the same behaviour*"? You seem to imply that your externally-connected potentiometer still *sometimes* works to vary the voltage to the fan - but on the face of it that's impossible, if (as you say) you remove the connections from *two* of the three terminals on a potentiometer. That makes your situation unclear :-(

Comment: I tried cleaning up the question @SamGibson I meant that the fan gets powered on with max. voltage, even with the 2 outer cables of the poti disconnected. Voltage control of course only works with the poti completely connected.

Comment: @idkfa - "*I meant that the fan gets powered on with max. voltage, even with the 2 outer cables of the poti disconnected*" That makes complete sense now, thanks, and this is the expected behaviour if you disconnect the two outer connections from the potentiometer like that.

Comment: @SamGibson I also tested now what happens when I disconnect the poti completely - same case. If I'm not completely mistaken from the schematic I uploaded this should also make sense as I did not interrupt the connection between IN and OUT when removing the potentiometer. So basically Andy aka should have given me the answer why my setup works sometimes when everything is connected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Feedback loop instability (as suggested by *Andy aka*) is a definite possibility. The feedback node is a high impedance input and can easily be affected by external noise, leading to unstable operation.

   For example, below is a warning from page 8 of the [ON Semi LM2596 datasheet](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/LM2596-D.PDF) - by adding that potentiometer on flying wires, your modification is breaking this recommendation to have short wiring to the feedback node:

---

[image: Warning to have short feedback wiring, from ON Semi LM2596 datasheet]

---

2. Another possibility is an intermittent break in the electrical connections being used (two in your case) to the potentiometer, leading to disconnection when there is mechanical movement of the flying wires to the potentiometer. I remember this happening to a potentiometer in an earlier question.

   The "rivets" (marked in red below, edited from your image) which attach the external metal terminals to the potentiometer track and wiper on its own PCB (brown in the image below) must maintain contact between the metal terminals and those parts of the potentiometer, and must not move when reasonable (gentle!) force is applied to the terminals by the flying wires:

[image: potentiometer with the rivets marked in red]

3. Yet another possibility is an intermittent / dry solder joint somewhere in your wiring between the potentiometer and the PCB, which makes & breaks contact as the flying wires are moved.

Answer (score 2):

Switching regulators like this operate as a closed-loop controller and this means there can be a susceptibility to self-oscillation if the feedback loop is meddled with. Opening the loop at the PCB pot and extending the pot wiring several inches is probably enough to cause all sorts of problems. It is likely that the closed-loop control has become unstable and you get strange results depending on where the wired external pot is positioned relative to the PCB.